# ValidateScript Parameter validation

Tags: powershell

This line:

```
[ValidateScript({if (!(Test-Path $_) -and (!($_ -like "*.exe"))) 
{ Throw "Specify correct path to executable." }
else {$true}})]
[String]$installerPath
```

The `Test-Path` validation returns True/False.

However `!` `-like` is not working as expected. Passing arguments with .txt, .msi etc file type does not validate correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply *swap* the if-else block and *remove* the negation (`!`):

```
[ValidateScript(
{
    if ((Test-Path $_) -and ($_ -like "*.exe")) 
    { 
        $true

    }
    else 
    {
        Throw "Specify correct path to executable." 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

For clearer validation, I would split up the checks and provide different error messages:

```
[ValidateScript({
    if(-Not Test-Path $_ ){ throw "$_ does not exist." }
    if(-Not ($_ -like "*.exe")){ throw "Input file must be an executable." }
    $true
})]
[String]
$installerPath
```

No "else" is needed since the throw causes an immediate exit.